# org-clock with multiple clocks

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I have multiple org-mode clocks running at the same time?

I've seen this [thread from 2010](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-06/msg00272.html) but was wondering if there was a way around this now?

For example, I want to clock the entire time I am working, but also want to clock how long it takes me to complete various tasks.

Comment: I don't think anything has changed in this area: there is still just one active clock.

Comment: @Nick that's too bad, it seems like a very useful feature unless there are other ways of achieving the same thing?